# listen to specific port no working on nginx

Tags: nginx, centos, port

The OS is Centos 7.3 , firewall is closed.
The server config on nginx is like.

```
server {
    listen       2001;
    listen       [::]:2001;
    server_name  _;
    root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
}
```

I don't have a domain now, so the ip:port is what i want.
but when I typed xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2001 on the browser, can't access the page.
But the 80 port works fine.

I'm a new guy to both linux and nginx, any clue will help.

Comment: Are you sure there is no firewall in your hosting platform that is blocking it? What error do you see on the browser when it fails? Where is the server hosted? What is the output of `netstat -tulpn |  grep 2001`